# JavaScript split and add a string

Tags: javascript

how to insert a string inside the url address after split ?
I have a simple code like this, but I just don't understand how split and join are work
I have tried "append" function but I can't get it right
I test and write it in
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_split

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var str="/image/picture.jpg";
        var test = str.split("/");
        for(var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
             document.write(test[1].join('/original') + "<br />");     
        }
        document.write(test);

    </script>
</body>
```

the output that I want is simply like this :

> "/image/original/picture.jpg"

note: thanks for the help.

Comment: Vikenoshi, please remember to accept the answer which has helped you :).  Thanks and welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 7):

Just use replace instead:

```
str.replace('image/', 'image/original/');
```

if you really want to convert it into an array for some reason:

```
var ary = str.split('/');
ary.splice(2, 0, 'original');
ary.join('/');
```

Comment: splice is not a string function in Firefox.  Doesn't work in Chrome and IE9 either...

Comment: @Keoki Zee - Thanks, meant to type "split" there, not "splice"

Answer (score 1):

vikenoshi,
You want to use the `Array.splice` method to insert new elements into your resulting array that you created using `String.split`.  The `splice` method is documented here:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Here is the code which should do what you want:

```
function spliceTest() {

    var url = "/image/picture.jpg";

    // split out all elements of the path.
    var splitResult = url.split("/");

    // Add "original" at index 2.
    splitResult.splice(2, 0, "original");

    // Create the final URL by joining all of the elements of the array
    // into a string.
    var finalUrl = splitResult.join("/");

    alert(finalUrl); // alerts "/image/original/picture.jpg"
};
```

I created a JsFiddle with a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/S2Axt/3/

A note about the other methods I'm using:

- `join`:  Join creates a new string from an array.  This string is constructed by transforming all of the elements of the array into a string, and appending or concatenating them together.  You can optionally provide a delimitter.  Here I use the `/` to split the portions of the path.
- `split`: Split splits a string based on another string into an array.

Comment: Thank you, this is a big help for me, I have been struggling for 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

```
var wholeURL = "/image/picture.jpg";
var choppedUpURL = wholeURL.split("/");
var finalURL = "/" + choppedUpURL[1] + "/original/" + choppedUpURL[2];
alert(finalURL);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/KLZUT/

Answer (score 0):

It's quick and simple

```
var str="/image/picture.jpg";
var elems = str.split("/");
elems.splice(elems.length-1, 0, "original")
document.write(elems.join("/");
```

Note I'm using the splice method with a first argument of the length of the array - 1.  This puts the string "original" in the second to last position in the final path, not matter how long the URL you pass in.  If this isn't the desired behavior, you can change the code to read `elems.splice(2, 0, "original")`.  This would put the string "original" in the second position in the path, no matter how long the URL is.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem with your code is that you're calling `join` on a string, not an array, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join.

The return type of `split` is an array, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split.  So doing

```
var test = str.split("/");
```

means that test is an array.  So then `test[1]` is a string of that array, and calling `join` on it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the Information, now I get it why join doesn't work on it.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var str="/image/picture.jpg";
var test = str.split("/");
test[3]=test[2];
test[2]='original';
document.write(test.join('/'));
```